# Continously calculate the an initial investment by its return vector

Tags: r

I´d need some help to create a vector that contains the value of an investment in every point in time. 
Imagine, I have the return (in%) of a single stock to 10 different consecutive months. Then I got an intital value of $100 and consecutively multiply the return of period t with the value of the Investment of period t-1. The output must be a vector because I want to plot the results. 
Unfortunately, I have no idea to create a code - probably its a for loop?

The Monthly return:

```
c(-0.09, -0.11, -0.2, -0.45, -0.11, 0.2, -0.27, -0.15, -0.24, 
0.16)
```

Value of Investment respectively:

100*(1+(-0.09))=91

91*(1+(-0,11))= 80,99
...

Desired Output Vector:

```
c(91, 80.99, 64.792, …)
```

I´m not quite sure how to compute this vector with a loop, function or other method.
I´m very glad about any help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
r <- c(-0.09, -0.11, -0.2, -0.45, -0.11, 0.2, -0.27, -0.15, -0.24, 
0.16)

100*cumprod(1 + r)
# [1] 91.00000 80.99000 64.79200 35.63560 31.71568 38.05882 27.78294 23.61550 17.94778 20.81942
```

or

```
Reduce(function(x, r) x*(1 + r), r, init = 100, accumulate = T)
#  [1] 100.00000  91.00000  80.99000  64.79200  35.63560  31.71568  38.05882  27.78294  23.61550
# [10]  17.94778  20.81942
```

Comment: Thanks! I´ve noticed that I got serval NA´s in my return Vector (r). Where should I add na.rm =TRUE?

Comment: If you have an NA that means you don’t know the return for that period right? In that case it’s not possible to know how much the principal has grown up to and past that point

Comment: I changed the NA to 0, which implies that the Investment doesn´t increase or decrease in that period. How would the function change when I have a return matrix (with y-axis as date and x-axis with stocks) instead of a return vector? I´m kind desperate ...

Comment: If the matrix is named `m` you could do `100*apply(1 + m, 2, cumprod)`